# Broken Hearted Man

Tags: fiction, character-development, romance

What word suggests the phenomenon of a man who has a broken heart? He feels like he has nothing to lose. This man will take unnecessary risks for the reward because death doesn't mean much to this broken man. There doesn't even have to be a reward just the feeling of taking the risk gets him off.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Stack Exchange is not like other sites. We are not a discussion board. We require clear, answerable questions which have the potential to help others. This is a "what to write" question, and therefore off-topic for us. Please see our help center http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and take the tour to see what kinds of questions are on topic here.

Comment: What word will describe this phenomenon? I know a lot of men that have gone through this.

Comment: I think this has the potential to be a good question, I would suggest an edit changing it from 'brainstorming' to a question to fit into the [tag:character-development] tag.

Comment: Thanks @Mike.C.Ford it was just something I was pondering on my way to work this morning. Had to write it out fast.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum care to point me to another website? ;)

Comment: Others here swear by Critique Circle http://www.critiquecircle.com/, although I've never used it myself.

Comment: After seeing the edit, this should be migrated to http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Lez Doo eet @Mike.C.Ford

Comment: I agree with @Mike.C.Ford

Comment: @Mike.C.Ford this question is currently in an unfortunate state that makes it hard to migrate -- it originally asked about character traits, got an answer, then was edited to be about word choice, then got another answer -- the edit invalidated the first answer (which isn't really fair to the answerer) *and* that answer would be out of place on EL&U, so the only way to migrate this is to delete that answer.  KNG, I suggest just asking a fresh question on English Language & Usage.  Be sure to check out their "about" page for general scope guidelines.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Careless crossing of the street during heavy traffic.
- If a good man, could help out someone in trouble for e.g: to fight off an armed thug in an alley.
- Pick fights, get beaten up but doesn't let go until passed out.
- Self abuse by using excessive alcohol, drugs, unprotected sex.
- Fast driving (but this is probably too boring).
- Gambles without restraint.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for behavioral tendencies or words that would describe him, I'll go ahead and list a few of the latter.

Desolate, Devastated, Depressed, Wretched, Heavy-Hearted, woeful, Heartsick, Despairing, Indifferent, Apathetic, or Fatalist. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Nice I like those, especially Heartsick. I stumbled on "Blasé" after checking out some synonyms from your list. "Dispirited" came to mind after reading your examples. Thank You!